# Header Slideshow

Tags: slideshow, custom-header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using short codes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73132/using-short-codes)

I want to add a slideshow in the header section of twenty eleven theme instead of header image. I have tried different plugin , but the only work into the post or int the widgets. they use the shortcode like [sample_slide id="1"] . But , if I could use them into the **header.php** i might be satisfied. But it doesn't work into the php code. What can I do ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73132/19726

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function to execute shortcodes within PHP.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[sample_slide id="1"]' ) ?>
```

Although I'm sure a lot of the slider plugins out there have template tags which you can use to insert the slider into your header.php file.