# Using shortcodes in PHP

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to use shortcode in my page, I'm starting with a simple test.

In `functions.php`:

```
function HelloWorldShortcode() {
    return '<p>Hello World!</p>';
}
add_shortcode('helloworld', 'HelloWorldShortcode');
```

In `index.php`:

```
[helloworld]
```

This doesn't produce `<p>Hello World!</p>`. Instead I just get the text `[helloworld]`.

How can I get shortcodes to work in a PHP document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referering to the [Shortcodes API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) you can do

```
echo do_shortcode('[helloworld]');
```

if your shortcode not in post. Or you can do

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', '[helloworld]');
```

but this will also bring other filters to work on your shorcode return html.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo do_shortcode( '[helloworld]' );
```

if you're going to use it in your template / PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

[Shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) are parsed through the function [`do_shortcode()`](http://queryposts.com/function/do_shortcode/). In some cases this function is applied as a callback automatically, for example when you are using `the_content()`.

To invoke the shortcode parser use something like this:

```
echo do_shortcode( 'I want to say: [helloworld]' );
```

But I would not use a shortcode like this, [calling the handler](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61567/do-shortcode-within-admin-page/61576#61576) without `do_shortcode()` is faster and easier to read.